# What is going on with this cross post?

Tags: support, specific-question, moderation

[How do I figure out the effects of wind on flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26326/how-do-i-figure-out-the-effects-of-wind-on-flight)

I don't remember cross posting this and this is completely outside of my interests.

It is more on topic here and if I did post this is there a right way to take a post from another SE site and move it to a site more appropriate and fitting?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could not remember plagiarizing an entire post... does anyone else have access to your account?  The author of a post can request it to be moved to a more appropriate site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't remember cross posting this

It was 3 years ago. I also don't remember what I was doing 3 years ago on that day. But in general, there is no suspicious activity on your account for that day. So short of someone accessing your computer (and we cannot verify that), you indeed posted that question.

> It is more on topic here and if I did post this is there a right way to take a post from another SE site and move it to a site more appropriate and fitting?

Well, no.
It is a plagiarized post, so there is no place where that would be on topic again. there is the original question and copy-pasting it will make it automatically off-topic everywhere.

It was already flagged as plagiarized when you posted. I was not a mod, and I don't know why no action was taken. It is now deleted, since it is against the rules to plagiarize content.

Comment: There was a link to the original post but not properly sited. I don't know but I would never take credit for others work. Thanks for addressing this.